# unable to answer meizu pro5 phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, smartphone, meizu-mx4

It appears that i am unable to answer the phone. I press the screen in all the appropriate places, but nothing happens. ALSO when making a call, the icons for a microphone and a speaker appear to do nothing. Am i missing something?
15.04 OTA-12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer phone *Swipe right*  - Do not press button - swipe right instead.

Comment: Nice that you figured out a solution, don't forget to accept your own answer though. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe there should be a hint for this, when the phone rings for the first time. I know i tried tapping it a few times before i noticed that everything in Ubuntu Touch is done by swipes...

Comment: That's the problem - Not everything swipes. The drop down menu options operate with a press. The only operations I've found on the phone that operates with a swipe is to accept or reject an incoming call and to flip through pages.